# Powershell Script for Windows server

Tags: powershell, csv, find

I have file csv:

in *.csv is:

```
1;folder name 1
2;folder name 2
3;folder name 3
4;folder name 4
```

... up to 1212

The problem is that, I want to find a file by name "1" from file *.csv and create folder "folder name 1" and move this file to folder. Script is for Windows Server.

Comment: well, what have you tried, what doesn't work?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Import-Csv yourfile.csv -Delimiter ";" -Header File,Folder | % {
    New-Item -ItemType directory $_.Folder -Force;
    Move-Item -Path ($_.File) -Destination (Join-Path $_.Folder $_.File) -Force
}
```